# Store only voice in PSR keyboard memory bank

Tags: keyboard

I tried to store my voice settings in a **PSR i455 keyboard**, but the style also got saved along with it.

[image: PSR i455 keyboard]

I want to store only voice so that I can use it while playing in ACMP mode. The problem is that each time I press those bank buttons where my voice is saved , the style that was saved along with the voice get selected. I want to use different voices while playing in ACMP mode but it should come from the memory banks. I don't know about higher PSR series but it should be possible to do this.

How can I store only my voice settings in the memory banks?

Comment: I don't see myself why this is Too Localized, it seems like a reasonable problem that others could have.  Since there is a lack of any other reasoning here I have re-opened.

Comment: I do not have this keyboard and actually right now I am using a midi keyboard without memory. I suggest you to send an email to Yamaha support I am sure they will find a solution for you. I was looking through their faq but I didn't seem to find what you're looking for http://faq.yamaha.com/us/en/category/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalkeyboards/portable_keyboards/psr400/#/?search_query=Store%20voice%20memory%20bank&current_page_id=1

Comment: Question is about a specific piece of equipment, and not Musical practice or performance.

Comment: @AlexanderTroup I looked through meta, and it looks like the MP&P hasn't dealt with the question of whether electronic music equipment questions are on topic or not. I'm voting to leave open and asking a question on meta: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/676/are-questions-about-electronic-music-equipment-on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Manual](http://www2.yamaha.co.jp/manual/pdf/emi/english/port/psri455_en_om_a0.pdf) for this keyboard, there are two ways to do this.

On page 31, it says that if you hold down the Voice button while pressing the Registration Memory button, it will recall your panel settings without changing your Style settings.

If you want this behavior permanently without having to hold down the Voice button every time you switch, there is a parameter called "Freeze Mode."  This is parameter 60, on page 50 of the manual.  It defaults to Off, but if you turn this parameter On, the keyboard will keep your Style settings even after you press a Registration Memory button.

Comment: Thank you for helping. The keyboard is in the church. So, this Sunday when I go to church I will confirm if this setting really works or not, and then I'll accept this answer if it works.

Answer (score -2):

best mode for storing voices are..... just press songs button... when u are in song file start saving you voices needed by you.... remember not to play that song file... start saving your voices... by pressing bank then 1 button to its right(bank  +  1 regestration button) you one voice is saved ....  repeat the process with other three buttons.... then go to styles button... play any style... select your voice... play it as u lyk.... remember transpose will remain the same... as voice were saved